# ¿cómo puedo cambiar el color de un navbar de bootstrap según el tamaño de la pantalla del dispositivo?

Tags: html, bootstrap

Requiero que para la versión Web se muestre de un color y para la versión móvil de otro color.

Busqué en la documentación de Bootstrap e Internet y no consigo nada, leí sobre navbar-inverse pero uso Bootstrap 4.

Se me ocurrió hacer algo como esto, pero no funciona:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  //EN ESTA lÍNEA QUE SIGUE COLOCAR NAVBAR-DARK BG-DARK
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-dark bg-dark" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
     <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown
     </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Sólo utiliza reglas media queries, algo así `@media (min-width: 576px) { .navbar {background: red} } @media (min-width: 1200px) { .navbar {background: blue }`

Comment: Gracias, lo había hecho de otra manera y no funcionó.